# python mysqldb update where variable where in list

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to update a field based on a variable where in list...

```
urls = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", ...] (long list)
time_now = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

UPDATE table SET updated_at=time_now WHERE name IN list
```

How would you do this in python?

This is my code so far:

```
update_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
urls = ["http://asdf", "http://qwer"]
cur.execute('UPDATE sales SET updated_at=%s WHERE sale_url IN (%s)', (time_now, urls))
```

Comment: Use `%s` instead of `?` for the MySQL database adapter as it uses a different SQL parameter style, otherwise the principle is exactly the same.

Comment: my problem is the syntax for setting updated_at to a variable at the same time as using the where in...

Comment: And you cannot use a sql parameter for that? `cursor.execute('UPDATE table SET updated_at=%s WHERE name in ({})'.format(...), [time_now] + long_list)`.

Comment: Here `[time_now] + long_list` creates one list of parameter values for the SQL parameter placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

try ;

```
"UPDATE table SET updated_at='%s' WHERE name IN ('%s')" % (time_now, "', '".join(list))
```